# Registering database Arcgis 10.2.2?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-spatial

When I registered a database data store to ArcGIS Server in ArcCatalog, the following error occurs:

> Underlying DBMS error[ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect
>   identifier specified No extended error.]

I set up the ArcGIS Server, ArcGIS for Desktop, and Oracle are all installed on one machine.
ArcGIS for Server 10.2.2 64bit
ArcCatalog 10.2.2 32bit
Oracle Instant Client 11.2.0 64bit
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition 11.2.0 32bit

I have successfully made the Oracle 11g "Enabled Enterprise Geodatabase" through the ArcCatalog, and it seems nothing wrong.

Database Platfrom: Oracle
Instance: orcl
Authentication Type: Database authentication
User name: gesbar2
password: gesbar2

And I have added the Oracle Instant Client directory to the PATH and environment variable, I am sure that the 64-bit DLL is found before the 32-bit one.

But i still get the error message. 
[image]

Comment: Sometimes you need to take the error message at its word.  This is an Oracle error, from within the Oracle client library, stating that your connection string could not be resolved.  You have not provided which connection string you have used, so it's hard to guess what was wrong.  You should certainly use `tnsping` to find a connection string which is compatible with both client and the server's listener.

Answer (score 2):

From ESRI support

http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000008951

Error Message

When creating a direct connect from ArcGIS Desktop installed on a computer installed with Windows 64-bit, the following error message is displayed:

"Failed to connect to the specified server. Underlying DBMS error[ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified. No extended error.]"

Cause

This is a known issue with parentheses in install path names on the Windows 64-bit operating system.

Solution or Workaround

Perform one of the following workarounds:

Reinstall ArcGIS Desktop on a Windows 64-bit computer to a path that does not contain parenthesis. For example:

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS

Fix the bug on a 64-bit computer:

1. Download and install the Oracle 10g 32 bit client from Oracle.com. This installs version 10.2.0.1 of the client.
2. Download and install Oracle Patch Number 4547817, which is '10.2.0.2 Patch for Windows 32-bit'. This upgrades the client to version 10.2.0.2.
3. Download and install Oracle 32-Bit Patch Number 5383042. This patch fixes Oracle Bug 3807408:

Externally authenticated usernames containing a '(',')' or '=' cannot be authenticated, additionally if a program name / path contains these characters, it may not be possible to connect (ORA-12154).

Comment: While I cant offer another solution, I doubt this is the "fix". This article is specific to 32bit Desktop. ArcGIS Server is installed to C:\Program Files\ by default, a directory with parentheses (  )

Comment: This is an ancient error description, from 32-bit ArcSDE 9.1/Oracle 10.2 days, unlikely to involved in an 64-bit Oracle 11g connection  at ArcGIS 10.2.x.